# git clone shallow-submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have added few git submodules and they are configured in .gitmodules. I am interested in specific commits of submodules. Hence I commit these commits and the can be seen in git submodule status.
Say for

```
[submodule "pcl"]
        path = libs/pcl
        url = https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl.git
```

the submodule status shows `757e28a75a0c6c0413085a2af070670828a48527` libs/pcl.
This means the above SHA1 will be checked out after running `git submodule update --init`

However, my problem is that I dont want to entirely clone the submodule pcl, because I am just interested in the commit from 757e28a75a0c6c0413085a2af070670828a48527 onwards. Is there any way to achieve this by writing a depth parameter etc in the .gitmodules file?

I have seen several posts, but most of them suggest to do a git add submodule. Since, I already have done this, is there a way, to edit the .gitmodule file with a depth parameter for each submodules.

```
git clone --depth 10 --shallow-submodules <repo>
```

would in my opinion pull 10 commits of the main branch and subsequently the tip of the master branch of all the submodules. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found a work around for the problem, and that might help others.

The goal was to shallow clone submodules. By following the below steps, the size of the project ( including submodules ) reduced from 30 GB to 2 GB. The project consists of lots of submodules that are constantly developed such as opencv, ffmpeg, pcl, mrpt etc.

.gitmodule just consists of the submodule name, path and the url ( hence no fancy config options ), like this

```
[submodule "pcl"]
        path = libs/pcl
        url = https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl.git
```

So, start with cloning, and then init submodules and finally update submodules.

```
git clone --depth 10 <repo>
git submodule init
git submodule update --depth 10
```

In case of error - error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object SHA, increase the depth for this particular module for example 100.

```
git submodule update --depth 100 <submodule> # for those modules, whose depth doesnt match. try with different depths.
```

When successful, continue with default

```
git submodule update --depth 10
```

Hope it is helpful for someone and further solutions re most welcome.